# Free Alternatives in Web-Application Mapping Software

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, webserver

Im new to hacking, i have reached a chapter in my book "*the web applications hackers handbook*" where im about to start bypassing client-side and actually attacking different technologies

well before i proceed i see mapping as an essential must expertise
i looked in Google for software came around Burp Suite, is quite expensive!
and others that were not trusting

**what are the free alternatives?**

for web spidering, http finger printing, an intruder, path testers, and any other type of needed tools i need to know to gather a lot of information to proceed a wider penetration

Comment: Do you mean *ethical* hacking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of program you can use for this.  First off I would mention that there's a free version of burp that does most (if not all) of what you're likely to need for running through the exercises in the book.

Good alternatives include

- [OWASP ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project)
- [Ironwasp](http://ironwasp.org/)
- [Conext CAT](http://www.contextis.co.uk/research/tools/cat/)

Comment: `nikto` is an interesting one as well.